# How does new method know the errors in the create method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

A sample code taken from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Controller

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
end

def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

A statement from this link

> The reason why we added `@article = Article.new` in the
>   ArticlesController is that otherwise `@article` would be nil in our
>   view, and calling `@article.errors.any?` would throw an error.

My doubt:
If there is an error while filling the form, how does the `@article` in `new` know about the errors caused to the `@article` instance of the `create` action? Aren't they both different variables? And when we `render 'new'`  shouldn't the `@artcle` of `create` method goes out of scope which holds the error description and `@article` of `new` contain no error information?

Comment: As stated below, `new` in `render "new"` is the template new.html.erb, not the action new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when there is any error in `@article` creation, there is no redirection but rendering which means that it will just `render/display` the new action view i.e `new.html.erb` without going to the new action or more precisely without making another call to new action. see this http://brettu.com/rails-daily-ruby-tip-28-whats-the-difference-between-redirect_to-and-render-in-rails/

On errors when it will render the new.html.erb it will use `@article` object which has all the errors which you get from these lines

```
 @article = Article.new(article_params)
 @article.save #save basically runs the validations
```

So basically after you submit your form, the purpose of new action is done. Now whole thing will be handled by create action in which on errors it will display the errors and uses `@article` object which you initialized and saved in create action and on successful creation it will make another call to show action using redirect

Hope it makes sense.